# How to use PyGame.sprite

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, sprite

I am ditching the python desk top and writing a zombie game with my friends. I have looked and looked but don't understand it. Could someone just explain how to use a pre-existing image and make it a sprite, then check for sprite collision? It is top down, by the way.

This is with python 2.7 and pygame 1.8.1.

Comment: This is with python 2.7 and pygame 1.8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so the pygame `sprite` object is a bass class which can be used to create other classes which you can then use to do things like collision detection:

```
class Player(pygame.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = self.rect.x, self.rect.y
        #etc.......
```